# Would having a romantic relationship matching feature be worthwhile?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I'm not personally interested in such a feature, but I just want to put forth the idea of an optional, possibly monetize-able,  romantic relationship matching feature for SE users. Is this a bad idea? If so, why not?

Comment: @Ano, relationship matching and following are very different.

Comment: I guess "If so, why not?" is too much to ask.

Comment: Well. If you're not interested in a feature and don't have any specific reasons why it is a good idea, honestly, it should probably die a quiet death without ever being mentioned. Features need to be *sold*, and sometimes, sold pretty hard. (This particular one has approximately a snowball's chance in Gehenna because of how extremely far removed it is from anything resembling SE's remit, but in general, that holds true for any non-trivial feature requests.)

Comment: That's right. I forgot. No one needs romance.

Comment: Last time I checked SE was a Q&A network not a dating site.

Comment: The answer is a pretty clear no (it's even mentioned in the help center): ["this is *not* a dating site."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @AndrewLi, but it's recently become a career site...

Comment: @Laurel I'm stealing that for my answer.

Comment: If I check back in 20 years and SE ends up doing it, can I get 1.6%?

Comment: Can we get the author of the "[a]lso, this is not a dating site" line?

Comment: @twoblacklinesinthemiddle When did it become a career site? SO Careers is just that, **part of SO**. It's not part of the whole SE network, plus it's *applicable* because software engineering and programming is a career field in high demand. Dating features are completely out of left field, and the actual amount of people to use would be next to none.

Comment: @AndrewLi How about dinner tonight, 8 o'clock? You pick the restaurant? *if this works out well we might already be a dating site ... not sure how this will make money but we have the whole evening to discuss the business case ...*

Comment: I'm totally hot for Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 27):

This… is a pretty terrible idea.

It adds nothing to the core QA experience, and doesn't serve the core goals of SE. It doesn't help add to the knowledge base, and is kind of the lowest common denominator feature. Also - one of the sections of our help pages says "[this is not a dating site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)".

While Careers and such *aren't* Q&A — they're of use to SO's core audience, and a proven money-maker.

Running what's essentially a dating site is problematic. We're often not had the best experience with people trying to use chat to pick up other users (it happens, and is terrible): some people are mild creeps, and we've occasionally had folks just go full abusive.

Quite frankly — *that's not what SE is about* and we'd need a different set of expertise to actually manage such an enterprise. Its probably going to cost more than its worth to run, and the potential downsides aren't worth it.

Lets leave the matchmaking to Tinder, iCupid, and my aunts. Or whatever the cool kids use these days.

Comment: I'm glad I asked though because now we have a record of its low value. Less than 100 out of the 1 million users don't like it. That's a start.

Comment: More like 25 of the 72 people who visited this question as of right now thought it was terrible enough to downvote it. One upvote. I'm thinking 25:1 is probably more favorable than reality (and you will probably see that this is the case if this continues to collect downvotes).

Comment: @twoblacklinesinthemiddle - A downvote to the question, is one of the only ways to indicate to the community,  I don't like this feature request.

Comment: As of the submission of this message there were 33 downvotes with 97 views. I'm not necessarily for or against this idea. Like I said, I just wanted to put forth the idea. I'm not upset. I'm not defending any position. My feelings aren't hurt. I'm just putting it out there. Jeeesus Christ...

Comment: Five years later, 54:3; so the 25:1 first guesstimate was apparently not too far off. Let's imagine at least one of the upvotes was out of pity.